# Inheritence Prints twice but starts withe

Tags: c#

Hey guys i'm not sure when i start my console with this code from the main, it prints the item twice not sure, cause i dont have a loop method at all:

```
        FoodProducts FoodProd1 = new FoodProducts("FP001", "Meat", 15.99, 200, 100, "Australia");
        FoodProducts FoodProd2 = new FoodProducts("FP002", "Bread", 2.99, 150, 50, "Italy");

        FoodProd1.Print();
        FoodProd2.Print();

class FoodProducts : Products
{

    private string origin;

    public FoodProducts(string id, string name, double price, int soldCount, int stockCount, string origin)
        : base(id, name, price, soldCount, stockCount)
    {
        this.origin = origin;
        //Need to find out why this code prints both lines and not in single line and why it starts from Product 2 when it is printed on the console
        PrintOrigin();
    }

    private string Origin
    {
        get { return origin; }
        set { origin = value; }
    }

    public void PrintOrigin()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Origin: {0}", this.Origin);

    }
```

**Updated from comment**

The `Print()` method as defined in the base class:

```
public void Print() { 
   Console.WriteLine("Product ID: {0}", this.id); 
   Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", this.name);
   Console.WriteLine("Prodcut Price: {0}", this.price); 
   Console.WriteLine("Sold Counter: {0}", this.soldCount); 
   Console.WriteLine("Stock Count: {0}", this.stockCount); 
   Console.WriteLine(); 
   Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Comment: What is your implementation of `Products`?

Comment: Is it because `Print` is called twice. Once in the constructor and once from the explicit call? Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I see where you are declaring your PrintOrigin method, but where are you declaring Print ?

Comment: @MarkHall: OP needs to show implementation of `Products` as @Cory points out.

Comment: Cool thanks, but when i take out the PrintOrigin() out of my class it doesnt seem to print the origin that i put in

Comment: @user1618490: at least post the output you are getting, please. In `PrintOrgin()` you call `base.Print()` ...is that output the same as that output by the next function call?

Comment: public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Product ID: {0}", this.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", this.name);
            Console.WriteLine("Prodcut Price: {0}", this.price);
            Console.WriteLine("Sold Counter: {0}", this.soldCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Stock Count: {0}", this.stockCount);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

Comment: *it prints the item twice* is not very specific. Please provide your console output and the constructor for base `Products`.

Answer (score 6):

It is really unclear what your want your output to look like. I cobbled together a Product Class based on your previous question. It's output looks like this.

[image]

As you can see, it prints the information twice like you mentioned. What is unclear is wether or not you want the origin to print each time you make the call, if so call the `PrintOrigin` method instead of the Print Method. Otherwise if you only want to print the origin upon construction take the `Print` Method call out of the `PrintOrigin` Method.

**First Example calling PrintOrigin instead of Print and removing the PrintOrigin statement from the Constructor.**

[image]

If you want to keep the Method call as Print instead of PrintOrigin declare the Base Method Virtual and Override it.
i.e.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FoodProducts FoodProd1 = new FoodProducts("FP001", "Meat", 15.99, 200, 100, "Australia");
        FoodProducts FoodProd2 = new FoodProducts("FP002", "Bread", 2.99, 150, 50, "Italy");

        FoodProd1.Print();
        FoodProd2.Print();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Products 
{ 
    string id; 
    string name; 
    double price; 
    int soldCount; 
    int stockCount; 

    public Products(string id, string name, double price,  
                      int soldCount, int stockCount) 
    { 
        this.id = id; 
        this.name = name; 
        this.price = price; 
        this.soldCount = soldCount; 
        this.stockCount = stockCount; 
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product ID: {0}", this.id);
        Console.WriteLine("Product Name: {0}", this.name);
        Console.WriteLine("Prodcut Price: {0}", this.price);
        Console.WriteLine("Sold Counter: {0}", this.soldCount);
        Console.WriteLine("Stock Count: {0}", this.stockCount);
        Console.WriteLine();
    } 

}

class FoodProducts : Products
{

    private string origin;

    public FoodProducts(string id, string name, double price, int soldCount, int stockCount, string origin)
        : base(id, name, price, soldCount, stockCount)
    {
        this.origin = origin;
    }

    private string Origin
    {
        get { return origin; }
        set { origin = value; }
    }

    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("Origin: {0}", this.Origin);
    }

}
```